# How can I open a URL from Windows Application (.Net) to the same Chrome Browser tab?

Tags: .net, windows, google-chrome, tabs, outlook-addin

I have a Windows Application where I am opening a Chrome browser through Process.Start(...) .Net method.

I am able to open chrome.

However there is a problem that whenever I am calling Process.Start(...) it is opening a new tab with the URL.

What I want to achieve is to open a new tab once and then use the same tab again and again.

This way there will not be as many tabs.

I can achieve the same through Web based. However my application is Windows application.

I have tried my best to find the solution through default switches mentioned at http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/.

But, there is no luck as such.

There is no way to get the TAB ID or pass the tab ID along with the URL as a parameter to Process.Start(...)

I hope that my question is clear to you.

The question is how can I open the a url on chrome with the same tab that my application has opened once.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent about 2 hours and find the only one solution:
To use built-in webbrowser control in your windows application.